# Run python script on reboot (boot)

Tags: python, scripts, reboot

I am trying to run a script once the server reboots. So, how can I change it. My script needs only one file to open and it opens in terminal. I read something about changing configurations or cronjobs, but how exactly to change it ? I want to do that because if I close the terminal obvious the script stops, so if I make it start on reboot it will work 24/7 I guess. What I do now is, open openssh, connect to my server, run the script, but when I close the session the script stops working, so I'm trying to make it permanently. Thanks!

Version: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start it manual have a look at screen. First install it with `sudo apt-get install screen`. Then you can start a screen session with one `screen -S NAME` and you can deteach the session with ´Ctrl+A D´, so it remains after you closed your ssh session. With `screen -r NAME` you can reteach it, if you need to.

For an autostart, you can place your script in the file `/etc/rc.local` for a execution on every boot. But watch out, `exit 0` must remain as last line. The commands in this file will be executed with root. If you don't want this, you can add a `su USERNAME -c "COMMAND"`  If you want to acces it later, I prefer `screen -dmS NAME COMMAND`, so you can reteach it with `screen -r COMMAND`. In completion: `su USERNAME -c "screen -dmS SESSIONNAME COMMAND"`

Comment: Thanks man, you're awesome. Never know about that, it even existed as an app, lol. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome ;) I'm here to help